# Run a docker inside a docker by python subprocess

Tags: python, docker, subprocess, teamcity

I've suffered a problem that run a docker inside another docker in CI/CD pipeline.

I've got a CI container let's call **build-docker**, I've got another container let's call **lambda-docker**. So basically I need to run the **lambda-docker** on top of the **build-docker**. The problem is when I use python subprocess call to run **lambda-docker** on **build-docker**.

If I call the docker through python then I will got an error.
[screen-shot: Use subprocess call to run a docker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2d3W.png).
Here is the code of Teamcity_Test.py.

```
import subprocess
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':
    python_version = '3.8'
    subprocess.check_call(
        f'docker run public.ecr.aws/sam/build-python{python_version} /bin/sh -c '
        f'"ls -lFa  /; exit"')
```

If I paste the command `docker run public.ecr.aws/sam/build-python3.8 /bin/sh -c "ls -lFa  /; exit"` to run on the **build-docker** directly it's perfectly working. Any explanation of why?
[screen-shot: running command directly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBghQ.png)

Comment: That code never prints out `screen-shot: use subprocess call...`.  Can you [edit] the question to include the text of the error message, rather than an image file?  The form you have has a major security problem (if I control `python_version` then I can easily root the entire host), can you pass the argument string as a list of individual words rather than a format string?  Using the [Docker SDK for Python](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) rather than `subprocess.call('docker')` would be better still.

Comment: Can you please explain why change the python_version will able to root the entire host?
BTW, thanks for the Docker SDK for python, it perfectly work docker in docker for my scenario!